Are There Bayesian Models Where the Posteriors of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ Are Independent?
In Bayesian inference, the Normal-Inverse-Gamma (NIG) distribution is often used as a conjugate prior for jointly modeling the mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ of a normal distribution. However, the NIG prior inherently assumes dependence between $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ in the posterior.
My question is twofold:

Are there any common Bayesian models where the posteriors of $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are independent, assuming that $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are both treated as random variables and not fixed constants?

If such models exist, what would be a common real-world scenario where this independence is a reasonable assumption?


I’m particularly interested in scenarios outside of the trivial case where either $\mu$ or $\sigma^2$ is fixed. If independent posteriors are not typically achievable, I would appreciate an explanation of why this is the case and how the data or likelihood structure enforces the dependence.

Suppose you have a single non-zero observation $x_1$.   For given $\mu$ the likelihood is maximised when $\sigma^2=(x_1-\mu)^2$, i.e. tends to suggest larger $\sigma^2$ is more likely than small $\sigma^2$when $\mu$ is further from $x_1$,  so it seems reasonable that the posterior will tangle $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$.

If there exists such a log prior $f_0(\mu,\sigma^2)$ that achieves posterior independence, then
$$
-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2} + f_0(\mu,\sigma^2) - \frac12 \log(\sigma^2)
=-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2} + \frac{x\mu}{\sigma^2} - \frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2} + f_0(\mu,\sigma^2) - \frac12 \log(\sigma^2)
$$
has to be written in the $h(\mu, x)+g(\sigma^2, x)$ form for some $h$ and $g$.
But this has a $\frac{x\mu}{\sigma^2}$ term that depends on $x$ and involves both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, with no choice of $f_0$ possibly canceling this term, unless $f_0$ involves $x$, which is not allowed in a bona fide Bayesian analysis.

This is a beautiful and simple answer. Thanks! This is also consistent with me constantly obtaining terms that wouldn't let me disentangle mu from sigma after pages of derivations. I have one more question that perhaps you'd know the answer for: is there some kind of principal rule why we model mu's variance (lets say tau) as linearly dependent on sigma? i.e. tau = sigma/lambda in NIG? Or is it just because it results in convenient conjugate prior? If it's for convenience then linear assumption would impose some restriction on the parameters, no?

I think it's just for convenience. Parameter restriction is not an issue to me, because $\tau$ and $\lambda$ are just hyperparameters on which we don't make inference.

True. Alright. I'm accepting your answer. It was very helpful. Thanks again.
